# Mysql Indexes, how many can I add the most?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have `id, member_id, topic_id` fields. Sometimes I use `id`, sometimes `member_id` and sometimes `topic_id` in `WHERE` clauses. Can I add Indexes to all of them? Will it make it slower? I am new to MYSQL optimization stuff, so thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unused indexes won't make a SELECT slower, but each index you add will slow down INSERTs and UPDATEs.

The maximum number of indexes a [MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) table can have is 64

Comment: Will it make INSERTs and UPDATEs slower a lot or only a little bit? And as I can see you are good in php/mysql, please check this question if you have time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138487/how-many-fields-is-normal-to-have-in-one-table

Comment: Generally, unless you are performing huge updates, it's not worth worrying about. For a large insert you can temporarily drop the indexes and rebuild them afterwards

Comment: Also, you can use EXPLAIN to find out if a given query is using the index you expected, and can also help you spot the need for new indexes

Comment: @PaulDixon, the `INSERTs` and `UPDATEs` won't slow down if you are using bulk transactions.  
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html 

--  I generally use for INNODB 

SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0; SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
-- ONE OF THESE
-- REPLACE INTO () VALUES () UPDATE ON DUPLICATE;
-- INSERT INTO () VALUES ();
-- INSERT INTO (SELECT ... FROM ...);
-- CREATE TABLE AS ();
-- ALTER TABLE (); 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=1; COMMIT; SET AUTOCOMMIT = 1;

Answer (score 2):

In general, you would want a separate index on each field if you will be filtering your queries only on single fields, such as in the following case:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE id = ?;
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE member_id = ?;
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE topic_id = ?;
```

If the `id` field is the primary key, then that is probably already using a [clustered index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(database)#Clustered). Therefore it looks like you may want to try creating two separate [non-clustered indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(database)#Non-clustered) on `member_id` and `topic_id`:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_your_table_member_id ON your_table (member_id);
CREATE INDEX ix_your_table_topic_id ON your_table (topic_id);
```

You may also be interested in researching the topic of [covering indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(database)#Covering_Index).